# Visual Basic Custom Install Code

Tags: vb.net, installation

I have a problem in coding an install application. I maked design for the forms, I maked richtextbox for licence, I maked textbox for the install key but I just don't know how to make form for installing the files. Can someone tell me code to make my install to begin then a form started (install form)? I don't have a lot of files. I just have ~5-10MB.

Comment: many apps have the licensing dialog (and supporting code) as part of the app rather than in the installer (some do both).

Comment: yeah but I want full-code customization and supporting visual basic code. Becouse I want to make from scratch the installer, rather than use other third-part application or visual studio add-ons.

Comment: the licensing code does **not** have to be in the installer.  if it is in your app, you can do all the customization you want.  you will have to have some code there anyway to test if it is registered.

Comment: I have an app for install. I coded all forms, designed but I just don't know how to code installation part (form there the file will be extracted). I have an alternative for this but still can't find the code for this. I can attach an .rar file in setup (I will make from setup+.rar an .iso with autorun feature), but is there any code to extract .rar file to a specific file which is choose by user?

Comment: sorry, I have no idea what extracting from an ISO and/or RAR has to do with using a custom dialog in an installer.  sounds like you have 3-5 issues going on with no clear definition of which problem you want help with.

Answer (score 0):

I know you are trying to build an installer application, but why reinvent the wheel. Microsoft provides InstallShield Limited Edition free for Microsoft Visual Studio.

Check this page out for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kt85ked(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I want to customize entire design. Add new layouts, new images and many other. I know that Installshield provide for free only default design (without customize options).

Answer (score 0):

Create a new form, put in a progessbar along with a timer.. use some copy/move code or something to transfer files to the required directory. use if...else conditions with the timer to check which all things got copied and accordingly move the progressbar

Comment: that files should be on internet server? I can't copile him into .exe?
Can you please give me copy/move code? This is my first project witch work with data transfer.

Comment: thanks for video. Ok, now I know how to make installer but how can I integrate my design in this custom installer? 
This is an exemple of setup I want to made: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ifrJkwuNxgY

Comment: how about you create the files in the solution. select their build action to none and copy the files during installation? idk if setting it to 'none' will allow acces, but its worth a shot.. check the copy code from MSDN examples